# SQL - concatenate values in columns but keep only first non-null value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following table in Postgresql. The first 4 records are the base data and the others were generated with the ROLLUP function.

I want to add a column "grp_1" that will display the first non-null value of the columns grp1_l1, grp2_l2 and grp2_l3

[image]

I can get to the desired result by nesting 3 "case" functions using the SQL below, but my real table has 4 groups with each 8 to 10 columns (so a lot of nested "case" function).

sql:

```
SELECT grp1_l1, grp1_l2, grp1_l3, case when grp1_l1 is not null then grp1_l1 else case when grp1_l2 is not null then grp1_l2 else case when grp1_l3 is not null then grp1_l3 else null end end end as grp1, value
FROM public.query_test;
```

Is there a better and more scalable to handle this requirement ? Any suggestions are welcome.
The id will not always have 3 digits, that is just the case in my example here

Comment: `coalesce(c1, c2, c3, ...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`coalesce()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL)  it's defined as "*returns the first of its arguments that is not null*" - which is exactly what you want.

```
coalesce(grp1_l1, grp1_l2, grp1_l3)
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking forward, did not realize there was a function specifically for that use case